# Modify an array of objects inside an array of objects in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach

Hello developers I'm trying to modify an array of objects inside an array of objects before deploying its result to Redux reducer.
The array is obtained through a request to an endpoint, reason  why i must to create an instance of writable copy of it , and then proceed on the process

Lest say i have this array:

```
 allProducts=    [
            {
               
                "product_type": "Bikes",
                "product_imgs": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "url": "Mountain Bike/Screenshot (200)"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "url": "Mountain Bike/Screenshot (200)"
                    }
                ],
                "product_name": "product test 1"
            },
            {
               
                "product_type": "Bikes",
                "product_imgs": [
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "url": "City Bike/banderaa"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 8,
                        "url": "City Bike/banderaa"
                    }
                ],
                "product_name": "product test 2"
            }
       ]
```

I would like to modify the items inside the array product_imgs of each object , but for that , having in mind this array comes from a request , i do create a readable copy an over that i set the logic.

```
let instance=[...allProducts];
```

then using a double for each (though i also tried using a doule for loop) i reach till every image inside the array of objects product_imgs of each object :

```
        instance.forEach(array=>array.product_imgs.map(element => {
          
          this.imgDownLoaderFirebase
          .ref(element.url)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .toPromise()
          .then((url) => {
            console.log(url);
            
            //then in this space once the url of some firebase endpoint is reached and else 
            //i would like to modify that object inside the array product_imgs which is at the same time 
            //part of the instance array.
            //For that i expose that this new url gotten would be asigned as the new 
            //value thus
            
            element = { ...element };
            element.url=url
            
            console.log(element);
            console.log(instance);//Printing the general array in order to check if changes committed
           
          })
       })
```

I want to specify that i use first a foreach and then a map in order to modify the inner array of objects result , but using a double for each doesn't precisely inmprove this situation:

```
instance.forEach(array=>array.product_imgs.forEach(element => {........
```

Then checking the logs , the element (item url) inside the array of objects  product_imgs of the array of obejcts instance , is modified , but the external array containing the inner modified not
[image]

How could i improve this?
Thanks

Comment: _"having in mind this array comes from a request , i do create a readable copy"_ - Why does the origin of the object require a copy of it?

Comment: Why does the callback of `.map()` not return anything useful? And why `.map()` at all?

Comment: well trying to modify the request straightforward throws me  an error of not being able to modify  a read only object....and the map , is a method by excellence in order to return a modified result , but guess is the same if instead of map i use foreach too. Let me check

Comment: exactly using the forEach , the situation doesn't improve

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to extract all product_img values from your array, you could try something like the following :

```js
// This line will convert your array of object into an array of array of urls, using a destructuring process
const urls = allProducts.map(({ product_img }) => product_img);

// This line will merge the previous result into a single-level array of urls that you can iterate onto.
const result = [].concat([], ...res);
```

Edit : I forgot to mention that this process will in fact return an array of objects including your id and url.

Comment: My goal is try to modify that array  of objects containig that url in the second forEach , and then give back the general container array already modified.

Comment: Can't perceive your point in this response . But thanks , right now im learning something new !!!!

Comment: You could use this method to extract your urls and keep their id in order to perform a Promise.all(), then merging the result into your initial objects using your prefered method, though I'm not sure which way to do is best.